# Combining unrelated filter functions together for 1 list

Tags: google-sheets, filter, formula

Im looking to combine two filter functions that are unrelated to each other (not the same filtering criteria) to have one list but from two different sources. Ive tried adding curly brackets but that just filters both lists and if one of them is false, neither appear.

[Screenshot of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSFCL.png)

These are the formulas that I have tried:

```
=iferror(FILTER({C3:D5;G3:G5},{B3:B5;F3:F5}={J2;I2}),"")
=iferror({FILTER(C3:D5,B3:B5=J2);FILTER(G3:G5,F3:F5=I2)},"")
=iferror(filter(C3:D5,B3:B5=J2),filter(G3:G5,F3:F5=I2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=ifna(vstack(
             ifna(filter(C3:D5,B3:B5=J2),tocol(,1)),
             ifna(filter(G3:G5,F3:F5=I2),tocol(,1)
             )))
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much. That worked flawlessly. Been racking my brain around all day trying to figure out. Appreciate you!!